# Replacing with Elements from a List

Tags: replacement

I have a fairly complicated expression with nested lists and I want to substitute a given string for each integer. Here's a simple example where ind is my integer-valued data structure and names is the list of strings.

```
ind = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {3, 4, 5}];
names = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
ind /. {n_Integer -> names[[n]]}
```

This returns two things: first, a list with the integers substituted by their string names (that's good) and an error (that's bad). The error is:

```
Part: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification.
```

though of course it has been used correctly as a part spec. The question: is it really incorrect to be using a list (and an index to the list) in the replacement rule? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This should do: `:>`, right?

Comment: Or even `IntegerName /@ ind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bill, this one always trips me up too. This does what you want, @Kuba beat me to it.

```
ind /. {n_Integer :> names[[n]]}
```

The way I remember the difference between `:>` and `->` is from the examples in the MMA help.

```
{x, x, x} /. x -> RandomReal[]
(* {0.430466, 0.430466, 0.430466} *)

{x, x, x} /. x :> RandomReal[]
(* {0.378563, 0.0598703, 0.504099} *)
```

Comment: Now I feel suitably embarrassed...

Comment: @bill Thank you, I was feeling lonely as a high-"reputation" user posting trivial questions. :^)